# Android - Path to Raw folder in the Res folder not found

Tags: android, tesseract, android-resources, illegalargumentexception, tess-two

My Package is: `com.abdulwasaetariq.odnvt`.
I have a folder named `tessdata` in `res/raw/`

In the Tesseract API, there is this init function whose documentation and prototype is:

```
/* @param datapath the parent directory of tessdata ending in a forward
 *            slash
 * @param language an ISO 639-3 string representing the language(s)
 * @return <code>true</code> on success
 */
public boolean init(String datapath, String language) {
    return init(datapath, language, OEM_DEFAULT);
}
```

Looking on the internet told me that the way to give path to a resource file is like: `android.resource://com.packageName`

But i am getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!`

Here is my relevant code:

```
    private static void initTess() {
    String dataPath = "android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/raw/";
    Log.d(TAG, "initTess: dataPath: " + dataPath);
    tessBaseAPI.init(dataPath,"eng");
}
```

The `context.getPackageName()` does in fact get me the correct package name `com.abdulwasaetariq.odnvt`

I wonder where the fault is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `android.resource://` is not a valid way to access [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) in your app's `res/raw/` folder, so the error message you see is being caused by the invalid path.

Try moving your files to `assets/` and using [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to copy the files to your device instead.

Comment: Ahan. I know about the AssetManager approach. But though what if i specifically wanted to refer to a raw file in res/raw folder? There must be a way to surely, right?

Comment: Yes--click the first link in my answer and look at Table 1.